# Faster alternative to itertools.product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, python-itertools

Is there a faster way to get all coordinate combinations for x, y, z than `itertools.product`?. For an example I have the ranges: x: 10-310, y: 10-310 and z: 0-65.

**EDIT**

For example i have to put all cordinates in a polydata like here:

```
points1 = vtk.vtkPoints()                      
for coords in itertools.product(x1,y1,z1):
   points1.InsertNextPoint(coords)
boxPolyData1 = vtk.vtkPolyData()
boxPolyData1.SetPoints(points1)
```

Comment: What is `x, y and z` here? What desired results you want to get? A 3D array?

Comment: The stepsize is here 1, but later on it should also work witch different stepsizes like 0.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html#numpy-mgrid):

```
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.mgrid[10:311, 10:311, 0:66]
```

I assumed you wanted the end points `310` and `65` inclusive.

Comment: Hey, thank your for the answer :) But how can i get each coordinate now? Like the coordinate for example (6,250,20) ?

Comment: @Varlor In that case you don't need the unpacking I showed in the answer. You could create the grid: `coords = mgrid[...]` and then index the result: `coords[:, 6, 250, 20]` which returns `array([ 16, 260,  20])`. But you could also index the arrays seperatly: `x[6, 250, 20]`, `y[6, 250, 20]` and `z[6, 250, 20]`

Comment: Ok i understand. But if i want to get all coordinate combinations and for example put all that combinations in a vtk.polydata like in my EDIT.
Then i would also have to iterate over the mgrid, wouldnt I ?

Comment: @Varlor ok, maybe I missed your point but you asked for a faster way to create **all** combinations. If you just want to iterate over **single** coordinates then you **should** use `itertools.product`. Or maybe check if `vtk` supports numpy arrays. Also please don't change the original intent of your question, it's generally better to ask a new question (more people check for new question and may have answers regarding `vtk`).